# Create list of objects with java stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

I have these data structures:

```
class A {
     String domain;
     List<B> refiners;
}

class B {
    String name;
    String signature;
}

class C {
    String domain;
    String name;
    String signature;

    public C(A a, B b) {
        this.domain = a.domain;
        this.name = b.name;
        this.signature = b.signature;
    }
}
```

Having a `List<A>` how can I use the java streams API to create a `List<C>`. Consider every member as public for now.

Comment: First you have to define the relationship between `A` and `C`. Nobody but you knows what these fields mean and how they relate to each other. Provide a method for us `C translate(A a) {...}`

Comment: @flakes the OP knows better, but to me it seems that C contains domain from A and name, signature from B, it is clear from the field names.

Comment: Do some research on Java 8 stream API and then try. Still facing problem then ask with minimum sensible problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making assumptions here, but you can use a `flatMap` and a `map` to create one `C` for each `B` in each `A`

```
List<A> listA = ...;

List<C> listC = listA.stream()
    .flatMap(a -> a.refiners.stream()
        .map(b -> {
            C c = new C();
            c.domain = a.domain;
            c.name = b.name;
            c.signature = b.signature;
            return c;
        }))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<C> cs = as.stream().flatMap((a -> { 
        return a.refiners.stream().map(b -> {
            return new C(a, b);
        });
    })).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where `as` is a list of `A` instances.

Comment: The block lambdas are unnecessary. You can do `flatMap(a -> a.refiners.stream().map(b -> new C(a, b)))`.